# QGIS expression not working in categorized symbology

Tags: qgis, symbology, concatenation, categorized-renderer, qgis-expression

In layer properties, when I want to work with categorized symbology, I categorize > value > `concatenate(code 1, code 2)` and after that, I click on "classify". And QGIS doesn't work (not responding), and I do not know what should I do.

Answer (score 5):

The expressions doesn't work because [`concatenate`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#concatenate) is an [aggregate](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#aggregates-functions) not string concatenator. The correct expression is `concat("code 1", "code 2")` or just `"code 1" + "code 2"`, I suppose that `code 1` and `code 2` are fields, that's why I added a double quote, if they are strings use single quote. Take a look to the [`concat`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#concat) function.

Answer (score 4):

Another option to concatenate strings or fields is using pipes `||`, e.g.:

```
'my string'  ||  "my_fieldname"
```

[See documentation for details](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#expression-function-operators-concat).